# Porque me convierte int a float, al crear un dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, folium

Se me presenta un problema al crear un dataframe a partir de un array generado creando clusters, y eso no me permite mapearlo en folium.
quiero que me cree el dataframe pero sin cambiar el type de 'int32' a 'float64'.

este es mi problema:

```
# set number of clusters
kclusters = 5

toronto_grouped_clustering = toronto_grouped.drop('Neighborhood', 1)

# run k-means clustering
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=kclusters, random_state=0).fit(toronto_grouped_clustering)

# check cluster labels generated for each row in the dataframe
kmeans.labels_[0:10]
```

el anterior codigo me crea los cluster correctamente, y me da datos tipo 'int32':
[image: resultado de clustering]

Luego creo el dataframe con el siguiente codigo:

```
# create new dataframe

# add clustering labels
neighborhood_venues_sorted.insert(0, 'Cluster Labels', kmeans.labels_)

toronto_merged = torocoordf

# merge toronto_grouped with toronto_data to add latitude/longitude for each neighborhood
toronto_merged = toronto_merged.join(neighborhood_venues_sorted.set_index('Neighborhood'), 
on='Neighborhood')

toronto_merged.head() # check the last columns!
```

y me crea el dataframe, pero me convierte los datos de la columna 'Cluster Labels' en 'float64':

[image: dataframe resultante]

Comment: lo más probable es que esa columna posea valores `NaN`

Comment: Excelente , gracias . borre los valores NaN, ;luego converti la columna en 'int' y ya me grafico con folium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo la pista del primer comentario recibido, busque los valores NaN posibles asi:

```
null_columns = toronto_merged.columns[toronto_merged.isnull().any()]
toronto_merged[null_columns].isnull().sum()
print(toronto_merged[toronto_merged.isnull().any(axis=1)][null_columns].head())
```

Eso me dijo donde estaban los NaN del dataframe, asi:

[image: resultado de busqueda de valores NaN]

luego procedi a borrarlos , asi:

```
toronto_merged = toronto_merged.dropna(how='any')
```

luego pude cambiar el data type de 'float' (no soportado) a 'int':

```
toronto_merged['Cluster Labels'] = toronto_merged['Cluster Labels'].astype(int)
toronto_merged['Cluster Labels'].dtype
```

[image: resultado de cambio de type efectivo]

y pude finalmente graficar los clusters. se puede ver el codigo completo, en mi github:
https://github.com/andresdq/Coursera_Capstone/blob/master/Toronto%20neighborhood%20ADQ%20copy%202.ipynb